What's the difference between NotNullWhen(true) and MaybeNullWhen(false)
I'm a big fan of the try pattern in C#, particularly due to being able to use static analysis to add nullability hints via the [MaybeNullWhen] and/or [NotNullWhen] attributes.
What I don't understand is the difference between them, are they not the same given the opposite condition? As in:



bool
MaybeNullWhen(false)
NotNullWhen(true)




true
not null
not null


false
might be null
might be null



Is there a semantic difference that I'm missing?

This might help to illuminate things

There's a bit of history here.
Nullable Reference Types, and those two attributes, were introduced in C# 8. However, the syntax T? (describing a generic type as "defaultable") was only introduced in C# 9.
So when NRTs were introduced, you couldn't write this:
public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, [NotNullWhen(true)] out TValue? value)

Hence, the need for a different attribute.
